# Make a client show in every tag at a specific position on screen and on top of all windows

Tags: awesome-wm

Pretty much what it says on the tin. I'm trying to get a small graphic to stay at a specific position on screen, regardless of which tag I'm viewing, and for it to always be on top. Unfortunately I don't even know where to start other than setting a rule for the client to be floating, so far. It would also be nice if the window's title didn't show in Awesome's task bar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is called "sticky". You can do "sticky = true" in a rule, the same way that you can set clients floating.

And for the taskbar: "skip_taskbar = true"

Comment: Thank you, that works. Also, I'm trying to position it to a specific location, but I want it on the second screen. It doesn't seem to like being positioned on the second screen when I try this.

Comment: Figured it out `c:geometry` works just fine, but it's very picky about the window intersecting any wbars.

Comment: I did not find it among shortcuts yet, but every window has a icon to make a window sticky, icon of a pin sign